# How can I create a cascading menu using Angular material components?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to create a menu which opens another menu like shown below.

[image: Concept of what is desired]

I managed to create something similar with a material nav list and a menu. I am having trouble moving menu to appear to the right of the initial menu/nav list to match my design.
I assumed I could use margins on the menu but that hasn't worked

Code:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <button
    mat-button
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
    aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu"
  >
    <span mat-line>Item 1</span>
  </button>
  <div>
    <button
      mat-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
      aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu"
    >
      <span mat-line>Item 2</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button
      mat-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
      aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu"
    >
      <span mat-line>Item 3</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button
      mat-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
      aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu"
    >
      <span mat-line>Item 4</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="sidemenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>Subitem 1</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>Subitem 2</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>Subitem 3</span>
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a menu that opens a menu, you can also nest the menus, no need for a nav list.

Code example:

```
    <mat-menu #rootMenu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">
        <span>Item 1</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">
        <span>Item 2</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">
        <span>Item 3</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="subMenu">
        <span>Item 4</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>

    <mat-menu #subMenu="matMenu" class="sidemenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <span>Subitem 1</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <span>Subitem 2</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <span>Subitem 3</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Comment: Should that code work as is? Replacing my code with what you posted creates nothing when served.

Comment: @NiceQuestion No, not as is. You have to trigger the rootMenu where you need it with [matMenuTriggerFor]="rootMenu". For example on a button, was not clear to me from your screenshot where to place the nested menus.

Comment: How can I have the Root menu shown without requiring an action... rendered at initialization?

Comment: You could try to open it programmatically at initialization. Here the link to the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#toggling-the-menu-programmatically